# Navigation drawer always open default view before

Tags: android

[image]

I'm beginner developer. I has develop project 
later on my senior. I has add view  for other fragment in drawer menu. when switching view it always bring me to default view before and now I cant change or remove this default. Sorry for my bad English, Thank you

```
 private int pageID = VIEW_MENU;
        private Stack<Integer> pageSeq = new Stack<Integer>();
    .
    .
    .
    public void menuAction(int id)
        {
            if(id == R.id.actionbar_search)
            {
                ((SearchListener)fragment).action();
                if(isSliderMenuOpen)
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
                return;
            }
            int page = -1;
            switch (id) {
                case android.R.id.home :

                if(this.pageSeq.size() > 0)
                {
                    if(pageID == VIEW_BOTANICAL_DETAIL)
                    {
                        showActionBarMenu();
                    }
                    page = this.pageSeq.pop();
                }
                else if(isSliderMenuOpen)
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
                else
                    mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);

                break;
            case SIDE_MENU_MAP:
            case R.id.actionbar_map: 
                page = VIEW_MAP;
                ActionBar map = getActionBar();
                map.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#FECC66")));
                if(this.pageID == VIEW_HOME || this.pageID == VIEW_BOTANICAL_DETAIL || this.pageID == VIEW_ALL
                        || this.pageID == VIEW_HOT|| this.pageID == VIEW_RAIN|| this.pageID == VIEW_COOL|| this.pageID == VIEW_REC)
                    pushPageSeq();
                break;
            case SIDE_MENU_AR:
            case R.id.actionbar_ar: 
                ActionBar ar = getActionBar();
                ar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#FECC66")));
                if(!((LocationManager) getSystemService( Context.LOCATION_SERVICE )).isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER )){
                    warningLocationServiceNotFound();
                    return;
                }
                page = VIEW_AR;
                if(this.pageID == VIEW_HOME|| this.pageID == VIEW_ALL
                        || this.pageID == VIEW_HOT|| this.pageID == VIEW_RAIN|| this.pageID == VIEW_COOL|| this.pageID == VIEW_REC)
                    pushPageSeq();
                break;

            case SIDE_MENU_ABOUT:
                page = VIEW_ABOUT;
                if(this.pageID == VIEW_HOME|| this.pageID == VIEW_ALL
                        || this.pageID == VIEW_HOT|| this.pageID == VIEW_RAIN|| this.pageID == VIEW_COOL|| this.pageID == VIEW_REC)
                    pushPageSeq();
                break;

            case SIDE_MENU_ALL:
                page = VIEW_ALL;
                showActionBarMenu(R.id.actionbar_search);
                ActionBar all = getActionBar();
                all.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#709256")));
                Toast.makeText(this, "All..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
                if(this.pageID == VIEW_HOME || this.pageID == VIEW_MENU)
                    //pushPageSeq();
                break;
            case SIDE_MENU_HOT:
                page = VIEW_HOT;
                showActionBarMenu(R.id.actionbar_search);
                ActionBar hot = getActionBar();
                hot.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#ef5c26")));
                Toast.makeText(this, "Hot..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
                if(this.pageID == VIEW_HOME || this.pageID == VIEW_MENU)
                    //pushPageSeq();
                break;
            case SIDE_MENU_RAIN:
                page = VIEW_RAIN;
                showActionBarMenu(R.id.actionbar_search);
                ActionBar rain = getActionBar();
                rain.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#a89c9c")));
                Toast.makeText(this, "Rain..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
                if(this.pageID == VIEW_HOME || this.pageID == VIEW_MENU)
                    //pushPageSeq();
                break;
            case SIDE_MENU_COOL:
                page = VIEW_COOL;
                showActionBarMenu(R.id.actionbar_search);
                ActionBar cool = getActionBar();
                cool.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#4e70b0")));
                Toast.makeText(this, "Cool..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
                if(this.pageID == VIEW_HOME || this.pageID == VIEW_MENU)
                    //pushPageSeq();
                break;
            case SIDE_MENU_REC:
                page = VIEW_REC;
                showActionBarMenu(R.id.actionbar_search);
                ActionBar rec = getActionBar();
                rec.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#f3424a")));
                Toast.makeText(this, "Rec..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
                if(this.pageID == VIEW_HOME || this.pageID == VIEW_MENU)
                    //pushPageSeq();
                break;
            default:
                page = VIEW_MENU; 
                break;
        }
        if(page >= 0 ){
            if(page != pageID)
            {
                if(this.pageID == VIEW_ABOUT  ||this.pageID == VIEW_AR || this.pageID==VIEW_MENU )
                    showActionBarMenu(R.id.actionbar_search);
                displayView(page);
            }   
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you provide  a screenshot of what you want vs. what you are actually getting on screen? this will help since you have a language barrier

Comment: ok i'm already upload picture. My problem is when use navigation drawer in listview page it should go to other listview page but, now it go to menu page instead because default is menu page.